# Marking points on an image

Tags: php, javascript, html

How can i mark points on an image on my html page after user clicks the image.I want to display some points on an image displayed on the page as soon as user clicks the desired thing.

Answer (score 3):

Place these 'points' as `img` elements, positioned absolutely, over the original image. You can specify their X, Y coordinates by using the 'left' and 'top' css properties.

If the original `img` element has relative positioning, you can state the coordinates in relation to the image you are putting the markers on to.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't need to support old browsers, have a look at the [HTML5 canvas element](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/HTML/Canvas).

- https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Canvas_tutorial/Using_images and
- https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Canvas_tutorial/Drawing_shapes

might be useful in this case.